# Space of sequences such thtat $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n|a_n|<+\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the space of sequences of real numbers $\{\vec{a_i}\}$ where each $\vec{a_i}=\{a_{i_n}\}$  is such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n|a_{i_n}|<+\infty$. Then how could we better describe the space? Typically, does the space have countable linear basis,is it complete with respect to the norm $\|\vec{a_i}\|=\sum_n2^n|a_{i_n}|$,whether it is finite dimensional?

One example that comes to mind is of the sequence $a_n=\frac1{2^{2n}}$. Hence, I think the space is countable. How should I proceed further. Is any representation like Riesz representation work here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Is it assumed that $a_n>0$? And if $a_n=1/(2^n)$ don't you get the (divergent) series of all $1$'s?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you actually want?

Comment: @coffeemath thanks edited. No, $a_n$ is not necessarily positive

Comment: @vidyarthi Your new sequence $a_n$ still gives a divergent sum.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I want wheteher the space is Banach with respect to given norm or finite dimensional or has a countable basis

Comment: Your expression for $||\cdot||$ is not a norm...

Comment: @BigbearZzz thanks, edited now.

Comment: @BigbearZzz why is it not a norm?

Comment: @vidyarthi because this expression can be negative whereas a norm can't

Comment: @vidyarthi because it doesn't satisfy the requirements that a norm need to satisfy

Comment: @BigbearZzz oh! extremely sorry. At least this must be last edit. Think the question is right?

Comment: Tip: if banach space is infinite-dimensional, it's hamel basis is necessarily uncountable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{(a_n):\sum 2^{n} |a_n| <\infty\}$ with $\|(a_n)\|= {\sum 2^{n} |a_n| }$ is  separable infinite dimensional Banach space. In fact it just an $L^{1}(\mu)$ for a suitable measure $\mu$. [ Without absolute value you don't even get a norm as pointed out in the comments]. Define a measure $\mu$ on the power set of $\mathbb  N$ by $\mu \{n\}=2^{n}$. Then $\int fd\mu =\sum 2^{n} f(n)$ for any $f:\mathbb  N \to \mathbb  R$ whcih is $\mu$ integrable. The identification of $f \in L^{1}(\mu)$ with the sequence $(f(n))$ shows that our space is nothing but $L^{1}(\mu)$. Note also that $(L^{1}(\mu))^{*}=L^{\infty}(\mu)=\ell ^{\infty}$.

Comment: so it is an infinite dimensional banach space and has no countable basis, right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Are you sure? It looks more like $L^1(\mu)$ with weighted atomic Borel measure to me.

Comment: @BigbearZzz You are right. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @BigbearZzz could you show what transformation would make it into $L^1(\mu)$?

Comment: @vidyarthi See the last part of my revised answer.